# How to automatically run tests when saving a file, in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, tdd, npm-scripts, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to natively (without extensions) execute `npm run-script test` every time I save a `*.js` file?

What steps are necessary?

I've created a Task in `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "test",
            "group": "test",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: test",
            "detail": "mocha --recursive --bail"
        }
    ]
}
```

But am not sure how to use it.

PS - I'd like to set it just for the current Workspace, as I don't use NPM in every project.

Comment: with extension `multi-command` you can create a keybinding for a `Save` followed by a named `Task Run` `workbench.action.tasks.runTask`